# SQL Select Neither Row if One Fails WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I currently have a SQL query that, as the result of some JOINS, returns a table something similar to the following:

```
 --------------------------------------
| id |   name   |      desc      | id2 |
 --------------------------------------
| 1  | aaaaaaaa | first thing    |  2  |
| 1  | aaaaaaaa | first thing    |  4  |
| 1  | aaaaaaaa | first thing    |  5  |
| 2  | bbbbbbbb | second         |  3  |
| 2  | bbbbbbbb | second         |  5  |
 --------------------------------------
```

From this query result, I'm trying to find the id field of all rows where id2 <> 4; however, if one of these rows fails, I don't want any of them to be returned (i.e. for id2 <> 4, I want only "2"; for id2 <> 5, I want no results; and for id2 <> 1, I want "1" and "2").  Simply doing WHERE id2 <> 2 will still give me the other matches for id=1, and I'm not totally sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the rows in your original data, use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.id2 = 4);
```

If you just want the `id`s that don't have 4, I would recommend `group by` and `having`:

```
select t.id
from t
group by t.id
having sum(t.id2 = 4) = 0;
```